# How can I find md5 checksums of my app once upload to playstore or app store?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

We have a requirement to **display to users the checksum of our apps** so that they can be checked against what have been download and installed via an app store (play or app store).

- We can generate checksums at the point of the app being built e.g. create appbundle or ipa and generate a checksum of this file quite simply against the package.
- When they are uploaded though, it's not clear if this is different to the binary that you download and there its highly likely that you'll never match the checksum?

Has anyone experienced this or can you help point to a solution - or is this a requirement that can't really be satisfied?

Many thanks,

Andrew

**Steps taken so far:**
Generate appbundle or ipa (we use flutter)
MD5 hash the resulting file
Store the hash for display on our site or the app/play store listing

Comment: On iOS this will likely be impossible (assuming you can even find a way to access the downloaded .ipa file to calculate a checksum). Apple will strip the download of images for 2x or 3x that are not needed for this device. So the contents will change. Also, I’m pretty sure that the .ipa is encrypted with Apple’s own certificate when downloaded which will not be the same as what you upload.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, this is useful to know and shows this isn't really a feasible task!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checksums won't match. I am not sure about iOS but as @GeoffHackworth wrote, Apple apparently modifies the IPA file after the upload and provides users with different versions that match their device.

The same is true for Android App Bundles. The Google Play Store generates APKs from the AAB for different device configuration, based on screen size, languages and other factors.
You can check the generated APKs in the Google Play Store Console. On your apps Play Store Console page go to "App Bundle Explorer" and scroll down to "Device-specific APKs".

[image: Device specific APKs in the Google Play Store developer console]

Comment: Thanks Alexander and Geoff - i felt this might be impossible to satisfy, especially since apps are signed when they go through the release process. I will use this information to help us go forward.